# UpdateView FileField not deleting previous files Django python

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have:

```
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
fields = ("file_one", "file_two")
model = User
```

And it works... but not always, I put in another file, and the paths change, but when I go a process the file in another def, it keeps the previous file values, I came to know because I checked my media folder to see if it was there and It was in the corresponding folder but also all the other files I had tested and read. I had to manually delete them and only the it took my new file.

How do I delete the previus file? or do I need to do:

```
def Inputfiles(request):
form = UploadFilesForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
if request.method == "POST":

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = UploadFilesForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/File_Upload.html', {'form': form})
else:
    return render(request, 'registration/File_Upload.html', {'form': form})
```

The only thing I cant think of doing is add a

```
request.user.file_one.delete() from [documentation delete()][1]
```

but I don't know where to put suck line if it would even work.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
file_one = models.FileField(upload_to='csvfiles', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['csv'])])
file_two = models.FileField(upload_to='csvfiles', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['csv'])])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override model's `save()` like this to remove old files during update:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            this_record = User.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if this_record.file_one != self.file_one
                this_record.file_one.delete(save=False)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: please explain in more detail, I can see where this is going but I ask for a more detailed explanation of what this does, I just want to understand what this does, because it may intrude in my user registration.

Comment: @Zealot91 this code will be executed during user saving. If user is not new(self.pk is not empty) code will check if file is changed and delete old file in this case.

Comment: But how will it react when I am registering a new user?
wait, I think I get it, this will just afect the file fields... right?

Comment: @Zealot91 yes it will affect only files.